# Django user groups login check

Tags: python, django

I created a group as a users for my django project.
I want to create users with no admin permission.
I just want them to be able to log-in website.
I have a form, I want that only users can fill this form. So I want to check if they are logged in or not.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`is_superuser` and `is_staff` in `User` model are meant for this kind of stuff. Create your users with `User.objects.create_user()` method and they will be created with limited access and no admin privilege.

Also for checking privileges on pages, use decorators like `login_required` or mixin and permissions classes to control access to pages.

And for advance Authorization checking there are packages like `django-guardian` which are awesome but need more understanding of django.

By the way, your question is not good and I suggest add more details and a specific problem that we can help much better.